# Flutter dependency error - Version Solving failed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-integration-test

I'm trying out integration testing for my app. When I am trying to add the integration_test dependency to my pubspec.yaml I'm getting this error:

> Because no versions of uuid match >2.2.2 <3.0.0 and uuid 2.2.2 depends on crypto ^2.0.0, uuid ^2.2.2 requires crypto ^2.0.0.
> And because every version of integration_test depends on flutter_driver any from sdk which depends on crypto 3.0.1, uuid ^2.2.2 is incompatible with integration_test.
> So, because flutter_firebase_login depends on both integration_test ^1.0.2+3 and uuid ^2.2.2, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_firebase_login depends on both integration_test ^1.0.2+3 and uuid ^2.2.2, version solving failed.)

What should I do next to resolve this error?

Comment: just update your packages. integration_test needs updated versions of your packages

Comment: @Xoltawn you mean run the command pub upgrade first then try to run the command pub get?

Comment: Try to Change your package version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because the `integration_test` package in your `pubspec.yaml` depends on flutter_driver, which required package `crypto v3.0.1`, while the `uuid` package you are using is at version 2.2.2, which required `crypto v2.0.0`, hence the conflicting version on `crypto`.

You should fix the versioning of the following packages in your `pubspec.yaml`. It's best to update them to the latest to avoid the above conflict:

1. [uuid](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid): ^3.0.4 (this package depends on [crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) v3.0.1)
2. [integration_test](https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test): ^1.0.2+3 (this package depends on [crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) v3.0.1 as well)